# How to put a paper which is part of conference proceedings and a book chapter in CV/resume/SOP etc

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, citations, computer-science

I participated in an AI competition and as a part of my submission, I submitted a paper about my solution. This paper was part of a conference (held alongside the main conference), and the competition organisers also published a book (subseries of a book series) which had the paper as a chapter. On ACM digital library, the bibtex includes the conference details for publication and the springer site (book  series publisher), the bibtex has the book as the publication. Both have the same DOI.

How should I mention this paper in my resume or CV? I am also applying for graduate programs, should I mention it twice, once under conference workshops and once under publications or just under publications?

Comment: Is it a chapter in the _proceedings_ book, by any chance?

Comment: @OlegLobachev i don't think so, the proceedings were part of MICCAI and the book is a subseries of LNCS, edited by the challenge organisers, a collection of papers from the competition and the conf is not mentioned in the generated citation

Comment: Ah, yes, LNCS. It is still proceedings of MICCAI, isn't it? I typically write "LNCS 12345, _Proc. FOOBAR '78_, Springer, Apr. 1879" in my bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List it under publications and (provided the styling permits it), add a note at the end: "Also appears as ...", to show the conference version. In reality it won't matter much, though.

Alternatively, list it under conferences with a note that it also appears in book form. "Also appears as ...".

Just don't give the impression that it is two different publications.

Note that in CS, "publications" and "conferences" overlap greatly, not quite completely, but to a large extent.